# Inter-process communication using physical text files

Tags: python, c++, pipe, inter-process-communicat

I am reading financial data from my broker in real time through a websocket API. The client is written in Python. I have another C++ program that reads that data, but the way I am communicating with the python script is through a physical text file.

My questions are...

1) Does constantly rewriting the textfile, opening, reading and closing it everytime affects performance? If so, what's a better way to do it? Performance on my application is crucial.

2) Would using named pipes be a better option? Or is that pretty much the same as writing and reading to a text file?

Comment: *Does constantly rewriting the textfile, opening, reading and closing it everytime affects performance?* yes

Comment: Writing to files is slow, pipes are fast.

Comment: Not sure I'd classify using text files as IPC IMO

Comment: I see... Named pipes would work for my application for IPC between my python script and C++ program? Is that one of the easiest and most efficient ways to do it?

Comment: Note that "named-pipes" differ on UNIX/Linux and Windows.  On Windows they are a communications protocol between processes which can run on different machines in a domain.  On Linux they are represented by an inode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern OS support many different [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Pipes, named pipes, sockets, memory mapped files, ... The choice of one solution or the other is very dependent of your application. But broadly speaking, all of them should be "better" than using a plain-old-file.

As IPC are objects managed by the OS, they are *not* dependent of the language used to write the various process. Some IPC have a file semantic (pipes, named pipes). Other require the use of some dedicated system primitive (mmap). But C++ and Python (and many other language) will support the required system call. In fact, IPC are *great* to help software written in different languages to speak together.

Comment: Just to be clear, don't try mmap'ing a named pipe!  (I know you didn't say that)